# Sugarcrm and Smarty : stripping tags.. or not?

Tags: html, tags, smarty, sugarcrm

I'm having a bug under a sugarcrm Enterprise 6.5.16 with the Synolia Pdf Template.
my client has set the template as follow :

Pdf template, having this content:

> Giving you the `{$fields.text_courrier_c.value}` by this pdf now.

So it brings me the content of the field texte_courrier_c. This field is a memo field.
So, it is filled with html. So, basically we have this value for texte_courrier_c

```
<p><strong>blablablabla</strong><br/>Test carriage return</p>
```

But in the display, she does not want to display the html tags.
so, she just wants to display

> Giving you the **blablablabla**
>
> **Test carriage return** by this pdf now.

.

this is what she made :

```
{$fields.text_courrier_c.value|escape:'htmlentitydecode'}
```

But, by doing this, we have a carriage return **BEFORE** the field's value and **AFTER** it, and that is not what we want.
like this :

> Giving you the
>
> **blablablabla**
>
> **Test carriage return**
>
> by this pdf now.

It is one sentence, we don't want a carriage return between the template's text and the field's value...

I tried to use the replacement for the

tag, but it does not work.

And the `{strip}` or `strip_tags` will erase every htmltag, but i can have a `<strong>` tag to keep somewhere in the field..

So, to make it clear : all i want is removing the **first** and **last** tag, so i have no carriage return between teplate's text and field's value. I tried to add some `{php}echo str_replace('<p>','',{$fields.text_courrier_c.value});{/php}` but ir does not work, since the tag `<p>` is translated by smarty used for my pdf template.

Do you have any idea on how i could achieve this?

Thanks you a lot!

**EDIT : found it :**
first of all, i made a logic_hook before_save calling the following function :

```
    function stripPTags(&$bean, $event, $arguments=null)
  {
    if(!empty($bean->texte_courrier_c)){
        $bean->texte_courrier_c = html_entity_decode($bean->texte_courrier_c);//déjà, on encode et on décode.
        $texteStripped = strip_tags($bean->texte_courrier_c,'<strong><br /><br><span><em><a><ol><li><ul><address><sup><sub><pre><hr><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><img><table><tbody><tr><td>');//on enlève tous les <p>, MAIS PAS LE RESTE
        $bean->texte_courrier_c=htmlentities($texteStripped);//on re balance
        //var_dump($bean->texte_courrier_c);exit();die();
        $bean->save();//et on sauvegarde
    }                                                                                                   
  }
```

And in the PDF templates, i'm requesting texte_courrier_c content by `{$fields.texte_courrier_c.value|escape:'htmlentitydecode'}`
It does work, even if the customer has to change his habits (like for charriage return, has to press Shift+Enter ...)

Comment: I'm not familiar with sugarcrm but depending to your issue, it seems there is an default output filter active that escape assign vars by a specific pattern. To avoid this, you could try `{$fields.text_courrier_c.value nofilter}`

Comment: i tried the nofilter, and yes, it works correctly, but does not fulfill my needs : all i have is
<p>blablablabla</p>, so i have tags showing. i'll edit my question, since it maybe not really clear.

Comment: and i tried to add `{$fields.text_courrier_c.value|escape:'htmlentitydecode'|regex_replace"/[\r\t\n]/":" "}` but i think my smarty engine does not have the regex_replace and it throws me error.

Comment: According to your question update, you could use strip_tags with a whitelist. Unfortunately as far as I know, this feature is not available in smarty cause the standard strip_tags function is rewritten by smarty. It seems you use a Smarty 2.x version so you could try `{php}echo strip_tags($fields.text_courrier_c.value,'<strong>');{/php}`

Answer (score 0):

If you've gotten to the point where only the newline char is the problem, then this should remove it. [Smarty nl2br](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.nl2br.tpl)

`{$fields.text_courrier_c.value|escape:'htmlentitydecode'|nl2br}`

Comment: this one just convert nl to br like said on smarty 'All "\n" line breaks will be converted to html <br /> tags'. I want to remove totally the carriage return. i'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: So then `{$fields.text_courrier_c.value|escape:'htmlentitydecode'|nl2br|replace:'<br />':''}`

Comment: Thanks to keep helping me @Matthew, and i'm sure your solution works, but i said i want to erase only the FIRST and LAST tag, because there can be a carriage return INSIDE the field's text, and these ones, i don't want them to disappear. I know it wasn't quite explicit, so i edited my explanation.